# timezone related issue when storing/reading Date using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have a Java EE 5 application (IBM RAD, WebSphere 7.5, Oracle 11).

I'm reading and writing a Date in my app with JPA, looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table="APPOINTMENT"
public class Appointment implements Serializable {
  /* ... */
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date lastUpdateTimestamp;
  /* ... */
}
```

Whenever I update the Appointment, I do a ...

```
myAppointment.setLastUpdateTimestamp(new Date());
```

... to reflect that the update happened "now".

There are two WebSphere servers, both pointing to the same database.

When my local dev machine's WebSphere stores an update time, it will store "now" as:

```
March 7, 2013 1:30pm EST
```

When the production server stores an update time, it will store "now" as:

```
March 7, 2013 6:30pm GMT
```

The problem is the timezones don't appear to be stored as part of the timestamp.  So when I browse to the application on my local (EST) machine, it will display the time as:

```
March 7, 2013 6:30pm EST
```

... which is actually 5 hours in the future, if you follow me.

My question is, how do I store the timezone to the database along with the date and time in the Date object?

Any info is useful, thanks!

Rob

Comment: That way lies madness, turn back!  If at all possible, define the database to always be in UTC and parse properly on the client side.  You'll thank yourself in five years.  (One guy's opinion on the internet anyway.) (Obviously if you *need* to be able to re-generate the original calendar on the wall time the user who created it was seeing, you do need to get some timezone information from somewhere, such is life.)

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion.  It made me consider changing the date field to a long and storing the myDate().getTime() long value as UTC time.  At the end of the day, I did something else, see my self-answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer, it turns out, is that the timezone is simply not stored in the Oracle TIMESTAMP field and there's no way to make this happen.  You have to convert the Date to the right value before storage.

For the record, here's the workaround solutions I considered:

(a) changing all my entity beans to store date as a long (UTC / epoch time) instead of a Date object (UTC = myDate.getTime()), and convert to dates for display purposes.  Decided it was too much code change.

(b) converting the time in my Date objects to GMT before writing to the database.  Decided against that too because that conversion occurs in too many places, and I'm certain some future developer will muck it up or forget to add it in a future code enhancement.

(c) I set the timezone of my dev webserver server to GMT, found instructions [here](http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2011/08/how-to-set-timezone-on-websphere-application-server/).

I went with (c).